# How to correctly type action creators mapped to props in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

In our project all action creators are defined like this:

```
export const actionCreatorFunctionName(arg1, arg2...) {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch, getStore: () => StoreState) => {
        // ... function logic ...
        dispatch(actionFunctionName(args...));
    }
}
```

Some of the action creators make HTTP requests and don't call `dispatch` before the request is resolved.

These action creators are mapped to props using the `connect` hoc like this:

```
import * as ActionCreators from "./actionCreators";

connect(mapStateToProps, { actions: ActionCreators })(SomeComponent);
```

The issue is that it seems to be impossible to configure the props interface for the component correctly when using this setup. We have tried configuring Props like this:

```
interface Props {
    actions: typeof ActionCreators;
}
```

But this does not work, because the `actions` prop is not really the same type as `ActionCreators` because the `connect` hoc changes the actionCreators from functions that returns functions to plain functions.

Comment: I think in addition to defining the actual actions, you will want to define an actions type with all the method signatures of each function, then import and use that in your props

Answer (score 1):

I think in addition to defining the actions, you will want to define an `Actions` type that you can export and use in your props.

```
export type Actions = {
  action1: (arg1: string) => void,
  action2: (arg1: string, arg2: number) => void
}

export function action1(arg1: string) {
  // ...
}
```

And then use the `Actions` interface in your props

```
type Props = {
  actions: Actions
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you are having trouble sending `state` from the `store` to the Component?
If that is the case, let's assume you have data in your store for an object called items, put the below code above your connect statement in the Component (this makes the `items` data available to your Component);

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  items: state.items
}
```

Comment: The question is about mapping dispatch to props, not state